# Why doesn't Ctrl+C stop generic host?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

[Docs contain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-up-a-host) simplest example of starting a host:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .Build();

    await host.StartAsync();
}
```

The output shows:

> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Which is not working. Nither in VS nor just with `dotnet host.dll`.
Why?

However, if I change `StartAsync` to `RunAsync()` it works.

Comment: What does the `StartAsync` approach look like?

Comment: @KirkLarkin, pardon me, code was wrong. It works for `RunAsync` and does not for `StartAdync`.

Comment: Approaches are identical except method call.